# Line going through circle (Current Sensor)

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

I'm using circuitikz, and I was wondering if it is possible to make a line go through a circle, in the way some people represent some current sensors, like this:

[image]

Here's an working example using circuitikz

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{circuitikz} [american voltages]
                \draw
                (0,0) node[ground] (terra){}
                to[V, l=$V_s$] ++(0,2)
                to[switch] ++(2,0)
                to[full diode,invert,bipoles/diode/width=0.3 ,bipoles/diode/height=0.3] ++(0,-2)
                (2,2) to[L] ++(2,0)
                to[C] ++(0,-2)
                to[short] ++(2,0)
                to[R,mirror,invert,l_=$R_{load}$] ++(0,2)
                to[short] ++(-2,0)
                (0,0) to[short] (6,0)
                ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result + a drawing where I wished to insert the current sensor.
[image: Where I wished to insert the circle]

Comment: Welcome! Yes, it is possible, but please add a minimal working example that creates a circuit so that people do not have to start from scratch.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat added! Thank you!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat answer is good; but notice that there are the components `iloop` and `iloop2` (section 3.9, instruments, around page 44 and following) that should do exactly what the OP is looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Schrödinger'scat answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518349/38080) is good, and very configurable (in colors for example) but notice that if you simply need the symbol you can use (since 0.9.0) the new `iloop` (part of the instruments), like this:

```latex
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages]
    \ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.6}
    \draw
    (0,0) node[ground] (terra){}
    to[V, l=$V_s$] ++(0,2)
    to[switch] ++(2,0)
    to[full diode,invert] ++(0,-2)
    (2,2) to[L] ++(2,0)
    to[C] ++(0,-2)
    to[short] ++(2,0)
    to[R,mirror,invert,l_=$R_{load}$] ++(0,2)
    to[iloop, name=myI] ++(-2,0)
    (0,0) to[short] (6,0)
    ;
    \draw (myI.i) --++(0,-0.5) node[below]{$i(t)$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, notice that `RPoltages` is to be preferred to `oldvoltagedirection` --- see the manual for details. If you have 0.9.5 or better, using styles to have smaller diodes also simplifies the circuit.

PS: Just for curiosity, why the `mirror, invert` on the resistor?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll take a look on everything you've commented!
As Ifor your curiosity, as I was learning how to use circuitikz, I was trying to invert the position of the label, before i found out that the "_" option on the label was the correct way.

Comment: @EduardoAlvesdaSilva --- `mirror` and `invert` only affect the shape, not the labels nor the voltages. Maybe it's not the better policy, but it's here since ages, so... 
BTW, if one of the answers here solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an arrow tip of that kind.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/arrow keys/.cd,
  main angle/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
        \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfarrowmainangle\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}}
  },
  offset angle/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfarrowoffsetangle\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}}
  },
  aspect/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfarrowaspect\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}}
  },
}%
\def\pgfarrowmainangle{90}%
\def\pgfarrowoffsetangle{20}%
\def\pgfarrowaspect{0.5}%
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=Sensor,
  parameters={\the\pgfarrowlength,\pgfarrowmainangle,\pgfarrowoffsetangle,\pgfarrowaspect},  
  setup code={
   \pgfarrowssettipend{0pt}
   \pgfarrowssetlineend{-\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
   \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code={
    \ifdim\pgfarrowmainangle pt>0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{\pgfarrowmainangle+\pgfarrowoffsetangle}{\pgfarrowlength and \pgfarrowaspect\pgfarrowlength}}%
      \pgfpatharc{\pgfarrowmainangle+\pgfarrowoffsetangle}{\pgfarrowmainangle+360-\pgfarrowoffsetangle}{\pgfarrowlength and \pgfarrowaspect\pgfarrowlength}%
    \else
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{\pgfarrowmainangle-\pgfarrowoffsetangle}{\pgfarrowlength and \pgfarrowaspect\pgfarrowlength}}%
      \pgfpatharc{\pgfarrowmainangle-\pgfarrowoffsetangle}{\pgfarrowmainangle-360+\pgfarrowoffsetangle}{\pgfarrowlength and \pgfarrowaspect\pgfarrowlength}%
    \fi
    \pgfusepathqstroke
  },
  defaults = { length = 4pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
                \draw
                (0,0) node[ground] (terra){}
                to[V, l=$V_s$] ++(0,2)
                to[switch] ++(2,0)
                to[full diode,invert,bipoles/diode/width=0.3 ,bipoles/diode/height=0.3] ++(0,-2)
                (2,2) to[L] ++(2,0)
                to[C] ++(0,-2)
                to[short] ++(2,0)
                to[R,mirror,invert,l_=$R_{load}$] ++(0,2)
                to[short] ++(-2,0)
                (0,0) to[short] (6,0)
                ;
                \draw[thick,-Sensor] (5,1) -- (5,2);
                \draw[thick,-{Sensor[main angle=-90]}] (1,1) -- (1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I am not a `circuitikz` expert. That is, I think this is valid Ti*k*Z answer, but I do not know if this follows the conventions of `circuitikz`. Please also note that using `figure` in the `standalone` document class does not make sense (unless one does some additional things).

Comment: @Rmano's nice answer is the correct answer to this question. I will keep this arrow for users who may need it in plain Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! As I'm still learning, this code will definately be useful later!